# Telethon. Автоматический ввод телеграмм кода Please enter the code you received: в эту строку в консоли. Python, telethon, telegram API

Tags: python, json, telethon

У меня есть скрипт, в который из текстового файла подставляются номера телефона для входа в сессию  TelegramClient. Скрипт сразу передаёт номер и в консоли первое что выводится, это строка Please enter the code you received: . Суть задачи в чём: мне надо, чтобы скрипт отлавливал этот код и сразу помещал в консоль, как с номером телефоном. Есть из файлов telethon session, tdata json. Я понимаю, что хочу что-то на уровне взлома телеграмма, но мало-ли кто-то когда-то сталкивался подобным и решал это как-то или были потуги решения в эту сторону, может подскажете что-то. В целом слышал, что есть сторонние серверы, которые как-то тянут этот код, так вот я и подумал, что может можно как-то через телетон или другой скрипт тоже его потянуть, без интеграции сторонних сервисов.
Буду очень признателен.
На всякий случай распишу всю работу скрипта: Запускается скрипт из файла phone_number берётся номер и подставляется сразу в скрипт, далее в идеале, подставлять код, после чего открывается сессия и отрабатывает дальше, подписывается на каналы из файла group_links, после чего скрипт отрабатывает снова и берёт следующий номер и так далее, пока не пройдём по всем номерам

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее всего это возможно, но только с помощью сторонних программ.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при запросе от TelegramClietn Please enter the code you received: , cкрипт должен сам его тянуть откуда-либо, пусть даже с открытого приложения телеграмм на пк с нужного диалога. Главное, чтобы нужный код вставлялся автоматически